# Treat octal numbers as decimals

Tags: java, string, decimal, octal

I'm learning JAVA and recently I had the same problem with  a few training tasks.

I have a some numbers and some of them are starting with 0. I found out that these numbers are octal which means it won't be the number I wanted or it gives me an error (because of the "8" or the "9" because they are not octal digits) after I read it as an int or long...

Until now I only had to work with two digit numbers like 14 or 05. 
I treated them as Strings and converted them into numbers with a function that checks all of the String numbers and convert them to numbers like this

```
String numStr = "02";

if(numStr.startsWith("0")) {
    int num = getNumericValue(numStr.charAt(1));
} else {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
}
```

Now I have an unkown lot of number with an unknown number of digits (so maybe more than 2). I know that if I want I can use a loop and `.substring()`, but there must be an easier way.

Is there any way to simply ignore the zeros somehow?

Edit:

Until now I always edited the numbers I had to work with to be Strings because I couldn't find an easier way to solve the problem.  When I had `0010 27 09` I had to declare it like:
`String[] numbers = {"0010", "27", "09"};`
Because if I declare it like this:
`int[] numbers = {0010, 27, 09};`
numbers[0] will be 8 instead of 10 and numbers[2] will give me an error

Actually I don't want to work with Strings. What I actually want is to read numbers starting with zero as numbers (eg.: int or long) but I want them to be decimal. The problem is that I have a lot of number from a source. I copied them into the code and edited it to be a declaration of an array. But I don't want to edit them to be Strings just to delete the zeros and make them numbers again.

Comment: `"numStr".charAt(1)` is `'u'`. And `Integer.parseInt("numStr")` will fail with a `NumberFormatException` because `"numStr"` isn't a number.

Comment: can you please post expected/example inputs and outputs?

Comment: Might be off-topic, but you have used your string variable inside double quotes. It should be just numStr and not "numStr". In parsing and getting character.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("010")` will return an `int` with value `10`. Unless you specify the radix explicitly, decimal is the default system your `String` will be parsed with.

Comment: Java only treats numbers as octal when they start with 0 when they literally are like that in the source code. Java does **not** treat numbers that a user enters into your program (through the GUI of the program, for example), as octal, so you don't need to do any tricks in that case. `Integer.parseInt(...)` does not treat numbers that start with 0 as octal!

Comment: Sorry. I deleted the "-s from "numStr"-s and tried to specify what I'd like to know

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to be able to read an `Integer`, given as `String` in a `8-based` format (Case 1)? Or do you want to read such a `String` and interpret it as `10-based` though it is `8-based` (Case 2)?
Or do you simply want to know how to create such an `Integer` without manually converting it (Case 3)?

Case 1:

```
String input = "0235";
// Cut the indicator 0
input = input.substring(1);

// Interpret the string as 8-based integer.
Integer number = Integer.parseInt(input, 8);
```

Case 2:

```
String input = "0235";
// Cut the indicator 0
input = input.substring(1);

// Interpret the string as 10-based integer (default).
Integer number = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Case 3:

```
// Java interprets this as octal number
int octal = 0235;
// Java interprets this as hexadecimal number
int hexa = 0x235
// Java interprets this as decimal number
int decimal = 235
```

You can expand `Case 1` to a intelligent method by reacting to the indicator:

```
public Integer convert(final String input) {
    String hexaIndicator = input.substring(0, 2);

    if (hexaIndicator.equals("0x")) {
        return Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2), 16);
    } else {
        String octaIndicator = input.substring(0, 1);

        if (octaIndicator.equals("0")) {
            return Integer.parseInt(input.substring(1), 8);
        } else {
            return Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the poor/bad wording of the question. I tried to specify it and I hope it's ok now
This is not what I wanted to know, but it contains things I didn't know so thanks.

Comment: Ah, your input (`String`s) should all be treated as decimal numbers, but they can have arbitrary many **leading** zeroes, that should get ignored because `Integer.parseInt(input)` fails on them? So you want to remove all leading zeroes of a given `String`? You can simply do that with regular expressions, `Regex`. The method `replaceAll` from `String` accepts such a `Regex`. Try the following: `input = input.replaceAll("^0*", "");` which replaces all occurrences of leading zeroes by the empty `String`. You can try it out here: [https://regex101.com/r/oW4oM6/1](https://regex101.com/r/oW4oM6/1)